# Everything works except Fedora

Tags: linux, fedora, virtual-machine, vmware

I'm taking an Operating Systems class online for college.  It requires us to have a copy of Fedora 13, provided by our instructor, running on a virtual machine.  On my machine, it boots to a message full of errors that ends like this:

[image]

I thought maybe it was just a problem with the instructor's virtual.  I tried installing a fresh copy of Fedora 18, to see if I could get it to work for the class. When I do that, first this message flashes on the screen:

[image]

Then it boots up to show an image something like [this](http://fedoraproject.org/w/uploads/thumb/f/f0/F18-alpha-wallpaper-standard.png/300px-F18-alpha-wallpaper-standard.png), and stops there.  The same thing happens even when I boot up in basic graphics mode from the Troubleshooting menu.

My teacher gave me another virtual, this one for VirtualBox.  It boots up immediately to this message:

[image]

And for reference, my CPU is an [AMD FX 4100](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819103996).  Fedora 18 on Virtual Box just goes to a blank black screen.

I have since tried Ubuntu, CentOS, Debian, OpenSUSE, Mint, Mageia, Windows 7 and Windows 8.  Every single one of them worked without problems.  Does anybody have any idea of what my problem could be?  If it can be fixed, and how?

```
CPU:     AMD FX 4100
Host OS: Windows 7 Ultimate
```

Please let me know if any other information about my system is needed.

**Update**

I have enabled Virtualization in the BIOS.  I then mucked around with the settings on this screen in VMware, trying every combination of item selections and check marks:

[image]

But none of them seemed to have any effect.  However, I have made some progress with Virtual Box.  My teacher's virtual still does not work.  However, the error screen has changed to be identical to the one that I get with VMware, word for word, address for address.  I've had better luck with Fedora 18 however, which has successfully installed in Virtual Box.  So, that's some progress.  However, the main issue is to get my teacher's virtuals working, because he wants to be sure all the students are working with the same setup.

Comment: have you enable VT in Bios ?

Comment: @RahulPatil: No, I have not.  But then again, I don't know what that is.  Any hints while I look into it?

Comment: @RahulPatil: Virtualization Technology? Do you mean on my host's bios?  Or on the guest? I didn't see any such option on the guest.  I will now check the host.

Comment: @RahulPatil: I found the option.  It was not enabled before.  It is enabled now.  There is, however, no immediately apparent difference.

Comment: Good to know....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would make sure that AMD-V is enabled in your physical systems BIOS.

- [Fedora 13 Virtualization Troubleshooting Guide](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Virtualization_Guide/sect-Virtualization-Troubleshooting-Enabling_Intel_VT_and_AMD_V_virtualization_hardware_extensions_in_BIOS.html)

#### BIOS

Something like this:
[image: ss of amd-v bios]

#### VirtualBox (enable VT-x/AMD-V)

Something like this:
[image: ss of virtualbox amd-v]

#### VirtualBox (enable PAE)

Something like this:
[image: ss of virtualbox pae]

Comment: In the virtualbox screenshot, if you click on "processor", you can enable PAE from there. That is the problem with his Fedora 18. Hardware virtualization extensions are good, but not required.

Comment: Turns out that Enabling PAE/NX worked, but only after *disabling* VT-x/AMD-V.  Strange.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anybody else has same problem with F18.i686 on VirtualBox:

The problem in my case was that GRUB could not load the graphics.
Using a chroot environment I did this:

```
echo "GRUB_TERMINAL=console" >> /etc/default/grub
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```